# Postgresql UPDATE query works on Windows but not on Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql

The following query executed on postgresql v10.3 running on windows works as expected. Suppose the fees_balance was 10000 before running the query, the query below gives back 17000:

```
UPDATE tbl_classes SET 
fees_balance=T2.fees_balance + 7000
FROM tbl_classes T2 WHERE CAST(tbl_classes.mobile_number AS TEXT)
LIKE '%71000001' RETURNING tbl_classes.fees_balance;
```

Now the same query executed on postgresql v10.1 running on ubuntu 18.04 gives -7000! Is this a bug in postgresql on ubuntu or am I missing something? Kindly help

Comment: I would be very surprised if there were a bug, especially one that only shows up on one platform. You'll need to add existing data and create a [mcve] so that others can check it. Now we don't know what data is in the table to begin with.

Comment: The query above works as expected on postgres on windows while giving unexpected results on linux. I stand to be corrected  but I do not think this should be possible unless there's SQL for linux that's different for Windows. I was able to resolve this using the advise below by changing the whole query to what works on linux because it seems to work on windows too.

Answer (score 0):

You have a FROM clause, but never refer to the table in it in the WHERE clause.  So every row of T2 meets the criteria.

That means that the specified row(s) of "tbl_classes" is going to be set to 7000 more than the value of some arbitrary row of T2 (which is also "tbl_classes" just under a different alias, but it has its own "row pointer")

Apparently on Windows the arbitrary row happens to be the one you want, while on Linux it is not.  This is just dumb luck.  You would only use a FROM clause here if you wanted to refer to two different rows of the same table in deriving the value to set.  That does not seem to be the case.

```
UPDATE tbl_classes SET 
fees_balance=fees_balance + 7000
WHERE CAST(tbl_classes.mobile_number AS TEXT)
LIKE '%71000001' RETURNING tbl_classes.fees_balance;
```